# C: array subscript is below array bounds

Tags: c, arrays

```
void page_kernel_only(int16_t page){

if(mode != KERNEL)
  {
    return;
  }
page = page << 5;
page = page >> 5;
int16_t help = 8192;
help = help & page_table[page];

if(help == 0)
{
    page_table[page] += 8192;
}
```

}

i get an "array subscript is below array bounds" warning and i dont know why, because a previous part of the code dont give me such a warning

```
void open_page(int16_t page){
if(mode != KERNEL)
{
return;
}
page = page << 5;
page = page >> 5;
int16_t help = 16384;
help = help & page_table[page];
if(help == 1)
{
    return;
}
page_table[help] += 16384;
```

}

Comment: mmu.c:154:26: warning: array subscript is below array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
  help = help & page_table[page];

Comment: Is that warning at compile-time or runtime?

Comment: Since the variable page is an "int16_t" it's signed. If it's negative the right shift may shift '1' bits in at the most significant bit. I'm not sure what your shifting is actually supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Right shifting a signed integer is _implementation defined_. Left shifting a signed integer will also generate _implementation defined behaviour_ if the sign is "shifted out".

Comment: `page = page << 5; page = page >> 5;` What is the purpose of these two statements? If `page << 5` overflows, the behavior is undefined. If it doesn't, the net result is that `page` is unchanged. If you're trying to clear the 5 low-order bits, you'd want to do the right shift followed by the left shift -- but a bitwise `&` would be a clearer way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `page` defined as a 16-bit signed int.  So if the value is greater than 1024, when you shift left by 5 then shift right by 5 you risk of the value becoming negative, which would generate the warning.

Edit:

If you want to ensure that the top 5 bits of `page` are 0, you need to do this:

```
page = page & 0x03FF;
```

Edit2:

`page` should be defined as uint16_t instead of int16_t.  That should take care of the warnings.

Comment: i need it to compile without errors and warnings, is there a workaround to shift back and forth without getting a warning?

Comment: Right shifting a negative value is _implementation defined_. There is no guarantee for not preserving the sign, nor shifting zeros in.

Comment: int16_t is the guideline for this task, we "shall" learn how to handle those problems and now stackoverflow tought me how to handle them

Comment: @noaH Fyi, per the C11 §6.5.7, p4: "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined.**". In short, if `page` is non-negative, and `page << 5` is not representable as an `int16_t` with value `page * 2^5`, you've already invoked UB.